# Xamarin iOS 24 hour timepicker

Tags: ios, xamarin, timepicker

I'm trying to get a 24 hour timepicker on iOS so that I can use it to insert a duration.

On android I got what I wanted by using a custom renderer. 
On iOS I also used a custom renderer (see code below) as I had found
on the internet. The problem is that it only views the picker dialog in 24
hours, not the set time.

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker), typeof(CustomTimePicker))]

    namespace IsalaSportmonitor.iOS.View.Controls
    {
        class CustomTimePicker : TimePickerRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
                timePicker.Locale = new NSLocale("no_db");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to check this:

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using PersonalTrainer.iOS.View.Controls;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (TimePicker), typeof (TimePicker24HRenderer))]

namespace YourNamespace.iOS.View.Controls {
    public class TimePicker24HRenderer : TimePickerRenderer {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e) {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
            timePicker.Locale = new NSLocale("no_nb");
        }
    }
}
```